# CMPivot to get registry keys

Tags: sccm, intune

I'm trying to get the content of regirty keys using CMPivot.
I'm able to it, th issue is when i display the information it creates new column whhile the names are the same (it adds 1 at the end of the name). So I was wondering if using pivot it's possible to juste add informaiton into the table without creating new column?
[image: CMPivot result I don't want]
.

While all I want is:
[image]

The Information I get are nearly the same. It's registry keys with their properties, values and key name.

I tried to do:

```
Registry('KEY')| join
Registry('KEY')
```

Or even using `| join kind=leftouter without` succes.
I tried to put the registry command on after another, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Add this and then you will get those columns you want.

| project Device, Property, Value, Key

If you just put | in place then you can use tab to navigate..